# Get variable value in scope from its string name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a string in a directive

```
patientCtrl.user.first_name
```

It is a string get from attributes, I need to get the value of the variable instead the string name

Answer (score -1):

Try `$scope.$eval('patientCtrl.user.first_name')`, this should work.